# Embedded LWC in Aura Component not loading on QUICK action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, quote, lightning-quickaction

I am trying to create a Quick action on Quote object, as LWC quick actions are not supported on Quote object trying to embed the LWC component in a AURA component and use AURA to tag to QUICK action.

Unfortunately the LWC and AURA components are not loading on first button click, I have to click couple of times to make the component load, looking to get some help to understand this behaviour and any workaround.

AURA Component Code:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <P>HELLO WORLD!</P>
    <c:standardProjectPricingModel></c:standardProjectPricingModel>
</aura:component>
```

LWC Component JS Code:

```
import { LightningElement,track,wire,api } from 'lwc';
import getProducts from '@salesforce/apex/StandardProjectPricingModelController.getProducts';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import Family from '@salesforce/schema/Product2.Family';

export default class StandardProjectPricingModel extends LightningElement {

    
    @track productOptions;
    @track error;
    value = 'Default value';

    @wire(getPicklistValues,
        {
            recordTypeId: '0125j000000xLQrAAM', //pass id dynamically
            fieldApiName: Family
        }
    )
    familyNames;


    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('Invoked successfully');   
    }
    
    

}
```

LWC Component HTML code:

```
<template>
    <p>This is a custom standard project pricing model </p>

    <template if:true={familyNames}>

        <p>Loaded</p>

        <lightning-combobox
        name="product"
        label="Select Product"
        value={familyNames}
        placeholder="Select Progress"
        options={familyNames.data.values}
        ></lightning-combobox>
        
    </template>

</template>
```

LWC Meta File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
   <isExposed>true</isExposed>
   <targets>
       <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
   </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

When I kept console log on connectedcallback function in LWC the log is being generated even on first click, but the modal window is not rendering, but on second click along with console log the modal is also coming. Anything I can change to make it work?

Comment: `are not loading on first button click` can you clarify what you mean by this? what does the user see? what is in the console? If you turn on debugger on caught exceptions are any caught?

Comment: Coz most likely this stuff crashes the first time because you're trying to render combobox BEFORE data is available. And the second time it is cached in the browser and returned faster, before CB is being added to shadow DOM

Comment: Thanks @zaitsman, you are right the combo box is causing the issue. If i remove the html code to render the combox box the modal window is opening on first click as well. Any idea how I can handle this, I kept a condition "<template if:true={familyNames}>" before combo box but still the modal window is not loading on first click. Updating code also in question for reference.

Comment: use wire function, not wire variable

Comment: sorry @zaitsman, I didn't get it.. is it possible to post a line of code change you are suggesting?